# How to read only the type key value in this

Tags: javascript

```
"DoctorA": {"name": "Pharmaceuticals", "title": "Switzerland, 120000 employees","type":"yes"},
"DoctorB": {"name": "Consulting", "title": "USA, 5500 employees","type":"yes"},
"DoctorC": {"name": "Diagnostics", "title": "USA, 42000 employees","type":"no"},
"DoctorD": {"name": "Fin Serv. & Wellness", "title": "South Africa,  employees","type":"no"}
```

am getting it using data.speakers.

I want to get each and every doctors types so i tried this.

```
for (property in data.speakers ) {
   //alert(property) contains all the doctor name.
   //i want type for each doctor indivdually.
  for (key in data.speakers) {
    var doctor = data.speakers[key]; 
    types.push(doctor.type);

}
alert(types.toSource());
}
```

Is there any way to make this.It will return all the data types in array format (yes,no,yes,no} i want like this,first i will get doctorA and get its type as yes.Not all values at same time.

Comment: You've got an extra level of loop there you don't need.

Comment: You don't need 2 loops, only one.

Comment: Those are strange variable names. You put in an array `names` the values of `type`, which can be `"yes"` or `"no"` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 2 loops, only one. You seem to want just this :

```
var names = [];
for (key in data.speakers) {
    var doctor = data.speakers[key]; 
    names.push(doctor.type);
}
```

In fact, from your comment, it looks like what you want might be

```
var doctorTypes = {}
for (key in data.speakers) {
    var doctor = data.speakers[key],
        type = doctor.type;
    doctorTypes[key] = type;
}
```

then `doctorTypes["DoctorC"]` will give you `"no"`.

Comment: It will return all the data types in array format (yes,no,yes,no} i want like this,first i will get doctorA and get its type as yes.Not all values at same time

Comment: @user3580511 That's not really clear. Is the updated answer what you're looking for ?

Comment: Yes exactly,But i want that type in a variable.I want to use the No for some other purpose like If(type==no).can you help me hope you understand my question